# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential). And a bit more

Tags: python, lstm

Full error:

raise ValueError(

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 507)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 507), dtype=float32)        
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

I am doing a LTSM AI that generates music. I am currently doing the parseing of data and some network stuff, I am a beginner.

here is the strand of code that is causing the error:

```
history = model.fit(networkInputShaped, networkOutputShaped, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=64, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

I am following this tutorial: https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/how-to-generate-music-using-machine-learning-72360ba4a085

If you need more info please tell me!